# What does <> (angle brackets) do on class names in swift?

Tags: swift, class

In a class declaration what is the use of <> angle brackets and the parameters declared inside in swift? Like as:

```
public class ClassName<T: Comparable> {


}
```

Comment: It's a generic. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It makes the class generic. The Swift standard library doesn't have a lot of examples of generic classes, but it has some very well-known generic structs and enums:

```
public struct Array<Element> : CollectionType, MutableCollectionType, _DestructorSafeContainer

public struct Dictionary<Key : Hashable, Value> : CollectionType, DictionaryLiteralConvertible

public enum Optional<Wrapped> : _Reflectable, NilLiteralConvertible
```

Read more about generics under [“Generics” in *The Swift Programming Language*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179).

Comment: Why do we need to use Generic? I I want to transfer an array from one class to another than is generic is useful? How?

Comment: That question is too broad. You need to read the section of the Swift book that I referred to in my answer, or be specific about what “one class” is and what “another” is and what is in “an array”.

Comment: Ayon, no, generics are not for "converting", but rather a way of declaring a class or struct as being useful for a variety of types, but doing so in a strongly-typed way. Your question about arrays is ironic, because Swift arrays _are_ generics (e.g. an instance of an array can be an array of a particular type and only that type, but all array instances enjoy the same set of methods, properties, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

It is defining a type parameter with a placeholder name, i which for ex in generic functions you can use as parameter.

Ex:

```
 func swapTwoWhatever<T>( a: T, b : T ) {
}
```

Thats why you can use T in a: T ..

Comment: This is explained in the same link posted before. Literally, with the same words. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179

Comment: maybe I forgot to say is a generic declaration, lol